# How to fetch an array from a prepared statement inside a class

Tags: php, mysql, sql, arrays

I wrote this code:

```
public function getDataAsArray($myQuery){
        $this->connection = mysqli_connect($this->host, $this->dbUsername, $this->dbPassword, 'portal');
        $statement = $this->connection->prepare($myQuery);

        $statement->execute();

        $data = $statement->get_result()->fetch_array();

        $results = array();

        while($line = $data){
            $results[] = $line;
        }
        return $results;
    }
```

I'm trying to return the result from my database as an array so I can use it in a foreach loop. This doesn't work before of exhausted memory allocator.

I have this working (unsafe) code:

```
public function getDataAsArray($myQuery){
        $this->connection = mysqli_connect($this->host, $this->dbUsername, $this->dbPassword, 'portal');

        $query = mysqli_query($this->connection, $myQuery);
        $results = array();
        while($line = mysqli_fetch_array($query)){
            $results[] = $line;
        }
        return $results;
    }
```

Could anyone help me fix this problem?

Comment: what is the value of `$myQuery`? tell us

Comment: You aren't binding anything, do you have placeholders?

Comment: @chris85 I'm escaping the strings before adding them to the query.

Comment: @Sanderbakker That's not how prepared statements are meant to work. You parameterize them, don't escape them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace:

```
while($line = $data){
```

with:

```
$result = $statement->get_result();
while($line = $result->fetch_array()) {
```

In your first scenario, `$data` is a variable, not a function call. `$line = $data` will always point to the first row you fetch, and then run "forever" until allocate all available memory.

Comment: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function fetch_array() on boolean. Even on the most easiest query like 'SELECT * FROM users'

Comment: Edited, take a look

Comment: Oh, the answer was edited. @Sanderbakker `on boolean` means one of the 3 function calls you were making was failing. In the future you should check each one before going forward. I'll remove previous comments because not relevant.